# Why is "ayant" the participle of "avoir", instead of "avant"?

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie

It looks pretty intuitive to me if the participle of *avoir* is *a**v**ant*, but it's actually *a**y**ant*. What is the story behind this V vs Y difference?

Comment: What I wonder is why would *avant* look more intuitive to you than *avoyant* ?

Comment: @aCOSwt: As a learner, I was taught the rule to form the present participle on the same stem as the present-tense indicative first person plural. *Avons* gives us *av-,* not *avoy-.*

Comment: @sumelic : Fair enough. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @aCOSwt Adding to that, if you build the participle that way, there are only 3 exceptions: *étant, ayant, sachant*.

Comment: You provide a rationale. Fair enough. I misunderstood your *pretty intuitive*. With regards to the irregularity of *avoir*, I was interested to know more about intuition. How *intuition* governs numerous irregularities.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think *ayant* was built on the subjunctive stem (found in *ayons, ayez*). The present participle of the Latin verb *habeo* had the stem *habent-,* which wouldn't be expected to develop to French *ayant.* (However, see Eleshar's answer for information on an alternative form of the present participle that apparently existed in later Latin.)

### How the subjunctive stem evolved from Latin forms with *-be-*

The present subjunctive forms of *habeo* in Latin have a *-bea-* sequence where the *e* would have evolved into a semivowel [j].

According to a book I found, *Romance Languages: A Historical Introduction*
(by Ti Alkire and Carol Rosen, 2010), in “Popular Latin” *-b-* had already been lost entirely before [j] in forms of *habeo.* For example, Alkire and Rosen give *[ajatis] as the “Popular Latin” ancestor of Modern French *ayez.* The complete loss of *-b-* in this context does not seem to have been a regular sound change, but rather an irregular reduction that occurred because *habeo* was a frequent verb that was often used as an auxiliary ([p. 140](https://books.google.com/books?id=1H7uBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA140)).

I’m not sure whether this reduction was complete before the split of the Romance languages, since Italian has -bbi- in the present subjunctive. But Spanish seems to agree with French in this: it has the present subjunctive stem *hay-.*

If *habeo* had developed regularly, I think the intervocalic *-be-* would have evolved to [βj] > [dʒ] > [ʒ] instead (see TKR's answer to the Linguistics SE question [How did French lose the Latin -v-?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/13130/how-did-french-lose-the-latin-v?noredirect=1&lq=1)). So the [β]/[v] would still have been lost, just later on.

### Why the subjunctive stem?

I don't know why the present participle of *avoir* would have been built on the subjunctive stem; maybe dimitris's suggestion about avoiding homophony is correct. *Sachant,* one of the two other French present participles that currently has an irregular form, also shares its stem with the present subjunctive (but in the case of *sachant,* the form looks like it might be traced back etymologically to the Latin present-participle form *sapient-*).

[Ewert (1960)](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.531113/page/n193) says

> 302. The close connection of the present participle-gerund with the pres. ind. and subjv. results in its being frequently re-modelled on these tenses, with or without the added support of the infinitive: *ayant* for *avant* (habentem), *pleuvant* for *plouvant, voyant* for *veant, croyant* for *creant* (which survives in archaic *mécréant*); O.F. *vueillant* (beside *voulant* < volentem) survives in *bienveillant, malveillant; (as)seyant* and *(as)soyant* crowded out *(as)seant* (< sedentem) which survives as a substantive and in *bienséant, malséant.* Other verbs in which both forms survive (one as the pres. part.-gerund, the other in a specialized use which has isolated it from the rest of the verb) are: *pouvant—puissant* ([by analogy with] *puis, puisse*); *sachant* ([by analogy with] *sache*) (twelfth-century)—*savant* being used only as an adj. or substantive since the sixteenth century; *valant—vaillant* ([by analogy with] *vail, vaille*) now a pure adj. except in *n'avoir pas un sou vaillant; en son vivant, sur son séant* are survivals of the O.F. substantival use of the gerund.

Comment: didn't notice *ayant* comes from subjonctif présent! This reminds me of *sachant*.

Comment: Pour ce qui est de *pourquoi* le subjonctif. Il n'y a pas de *raison*. Il faut partir de l'observation qu'il s'agit ici d'un cas de *supplétion*. Puis la ranger, avec les autres, dans un espace thématique et mentionner sur ce sujet l'hypothèse avancée par Morin (1987) de l'existence de *règles d'implication*. Ces "régles" sont des règles *par défaut*.

Comment: Le comm ci-dessus laisse évidemment entrevoir un travail long et compliqué. C'est pourquoi, en regrettant encore ici que l'OP ne poursuive pas son *pretty intuitive*, je préfère, pour ma part, rejoindre Claire Blanche-Benveniste et observer que *avoir* est un des 5 verbes les plus utilisés en français. Et que, comme c'est aussi le cas dans beaucoup d'autres langues, les verbes les plus utilisés sont aussi les plus irréguliers.

Comment: Toujours à propos de mon 1er comm, Peut-être peut-on retrouver sur le net un travail mené dans les années 2000 sur le sujet par Gilles Boyer de l'Université de Nancy.

Comment: Gilles Boy**é**. Pardon!

Answer (score 2):

For *habere*, there is attested active participle form *habeant-*, probably from late Latin that evolved to the French dialect of proto-romance. From there, it would be the same evolution as the subjunctive itself.

The forms based on *habeant-* are easy to find just by googling, but if you need some better source, e.g. Foley,J: *Theoretical Morphology of the French Verb* indicates there seem to be quite a few other verbs where the late Latin seems to have used the subjunctive stem as a source for the active participle. My guess would be this was an analogy with the prevalent a-form verbs of the first conjugation, ending with *-ant-* along with the pressure to maintain the stem vowel *-e-*.

Comment: I thought -vj- would be expected to merge with -bj- and also develop into -ž-. This [Linguistics SE question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/13130/how-did-french-lose-the-latin-v?noredirect=1&lq=1) gives the example of alleger from alleviare and the linked duplicate gives the example of abbreviare to abréger.

Comment: Actually, I see that you wrote the answer to the duplicate there!

Comment: Good point. No idea about the exact rules - _abbreviare_ gives _abréger_. Might have something to do with timing perhaps? Earlier /vj/ > /ž/, later/secondary /vj/ > /j/? Or perhaps stress comes into play? Will have to research more. In any case the subjunctive-like participle form goes back to Latin.

Comment: I added a cite to my answer that gives an explanation. The -be- is supposed to have been reduced to -[j]- already in “Popular Latin”, as a special reduction in the verb habeo

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess (and not quite obvious as I thought initially). In this way the confusion with the fundamental word *[avant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/avant)* was avoided.

Comment: L'explication est séduisante. Néanmoins... bon... faut... hmmm... faut **voir**... ;-)

Comment: @aCOSwt J'ai dis plusieurs fois : Non locuteurs natif:-)!

Comment: @aCOSwt avoir vient du latin habeo, avant du bas latin abante. Si avant est apparu le premier c'est bon. Autrement, il me faut...effacer la réponse:-)!

Comment: @aCOSwt Littre : Avant : Bourguig. aivan ; provenç. avant ; ital. avanti ; du latin abante (qu'on trouve dans des inscriptions), de ab, de, et ante, avant (voy. ⤷AINZ).

Comment: @aCOSwt Littte Avoir: Bourguign. aivoy ; provenç. aver ; espagn. haber ; portug. haver ; ital. avere ; du lat. habere. Comparez l'allemand haben, le gothique haban. Dans l'ancienne langue, on disait non pas il y a, mais simplement il a (illud habet), ce qui voulait le cas régime du substantif : il avoit un chastel, il y avait un château ; chastel est le cas régime : chastels ou chastaus serait le nominatif. Pourtant, l'adverbe y se montre dans cette locution dès le XIIIe siècle. La forme archaïque, sans y, s'est conservée dans le style marotique, au moins avec la négation (...)

Comment: (...) Entre Leclerc et son ami Coras, N'a pas longtemps, s'émurent grands débats, RAC., Épigr. Il y a lieu de remarquer avret dans un texte du Xe siècle ; c'est, étymologiquement, l'équivalent de habuerat, où l'u, comme dans ces formations, devint un v, habverat, avec l'accent par conséquent sur há. On s'était étonné que le plus-que-parfait latin n'eût laissé aucune trace dans les langues romanes, où en effet on ne le trouve pas ; mais ces textes du Xe siècle montrent qu'il a existé, bien que transitoirement.

Comment: Je ne sais pas si le sudit y a une influence sur ayant...

Comment: I don't think the original answer is true, I'd say it may more due to the latin fact that "v" is pronounced "y", meaning that originally the auxiliary "avoir" evolved from the original form with a "y" to the version with "v". It might be that "ayant" just didn't evolve, so more related to the last comment

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: Latin V is pronounced as [u] (as a vowel), as [w] (as a semivowel), or as [β] or [v] (as a consonant that developed from the semivowel [w]). It wasn't ever pronounced like "y".

Comment: I don't find this answer at all compelling; French has plenty of homophones, including between common grammatical words (consider *ce* vs. *se*, or the preposition *en* vs. the pronoun *en*). I can well believe that the existence of the preposition *avant* is part of the answer here, but if you want to claim that it's the whole story, then I think you need better evidence than just "I think it is quite obvious."

Comment: @ruakh C'est noté:-)! Je viens de l'éditer. Merci.

Answer (score 0):

I can find nothing else but a piece of puzzling information that could concern the origin of this form;  it's the present participle of the verb « ( [avair)](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ayant#Gallo) » in Gallo;

This verb correspond to « [avoir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avair#gallo) », however no claim is made of « ayant » having been borrowed.